# Google SQL Cloud operations callback?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I currently have an application which triggers import jobs to Google SQL Cloud using the their API:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/import

This works great. However, this is only a request to import an SQL file. I have to check that the request was successful a minute or two afterwards.

What I would like, is to somehow register a callback to notify my application when the operation is complete. Then I can delete the bucket item and mark the data as persisted.

I have no idea if this is possible, but would be grateful for any advice. Perhaps the PubSub system API could be used for this, but so far have been unable to find any documentation on how this would be done.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no out of the box way to do this. You need to poll the operation status to determine when it's finished.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I assumed this was the case, but appreciate the confirmation.